# Bottom Navigation and Fragments go out of order when back button is pressed

Tags: java, android

I am new to android programming and I am having an issue primarily with the back button.

An Example =

Home Fragment -> Chat Fragment -> Notification Fragment -> **Back Button pressed** -> Chat Fragment -> **Back Button pressed** -> Home Fragment.

What is selected =
Home selected -> Chat selected -> Notification selected -> **Back Button pressed** -> Notification still selected -> **Back Button pressed** -> Chat Fragment.

**PICTURES IF EXPLANATION IS BAD**

[image]

**ANY HELP IS APPERCIATED**

**MAIN ACTIVITY**

```
bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNav);
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(bottomNavMethod);
/*

*/

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener bottomNavMethod = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            Fragment fragment;
            ChatGroupArray chatGroupArray = new ChatGroupArray();
            menuItem.setCheckable(true);
            Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.home:

                    if (!(currentFragment instanceof HomeFragment)) {
                        fragment = new HomeFragment();
                        loadFragment(fragment, "HomeFragment");
                        return true;
                    }


                case R.id.chat:
                    if (!(currentFragment instanceof chatFragment)) {
                        fragment = new chatFragment();
                        loadFragment(fragment, "chatFragment");
                        return true;
                    }


                case R.id.notification:

                    if (!(currentFragment instanceof NotificationFragment)) {
                        fragment = new NotificationFragment();
                        loadFragment(fragment, "NotificationFragment");
                        return true;
                    }



                case R.id.account:
                    if (!(currentFragment instanceof AccountFragment)) {
                        fragment = new AccountFragment();
                        loadFragment(fragment, "AccountFragment");
                        return true;
                    }





            }
            //getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,fragment).commit();

            return true;
        }
    };
```

**loadFragment**

```
public void loadFragment(Fragment fragment, String tag) {

        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(tag);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

**ON BACK PRESS OVERRIDE**

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // if your using fragment then you can do this way
        int fragments
                = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
        if (fragments == 1) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .show();


        } else {
            if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                Fragment selectedFragment = null;
                List<Fragment> f = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
                for (Fragment fragment : f) {
                    if (fragment != null && fragment.isVisible()) {
                        selectedFragment = fragment;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (selectedFragment instanceof HomeFragment) {
                    bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.home);
                    
                }
                if (selectedFragment instanceof chatFragment) {
                    bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.chat);
                    
                }
                if (selectedFragment instanceof NotificationFragment) {
                    bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.notification);
                    
                }if(selectedFragment instanceof AccountFragment){
                    bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.account);
                   
                } else {
                    super.onBackPressed(); }

            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What behavior did you want to achieve?  Do you want to go to the home fragment on the back press or the last used fragment? btw using the Navigation component might help you also it is easy to use. https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started

Comment: I want it to go to the last fragment while also changing the bottom navigation selector to the fragment i went back to. Currently when i press the back button only the fragment changes and the bottom nav stays the same

Comment: you cant do that with BottomNavigationView you should made your custom bottom menu with relative layout or something ... then put ur fragments inside view pager then handle your view pager selection inside button back press method